# Angular2+: Register simple service worker on root scope

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have written a very basic Service Worker on my Angular2+ (v.4.1.0 approx.) app. The sw.js file is on the`src`directory.

The folder structure is something like:

```
src/
   app/
   assets/
   environments/
   favicon.ico
   index.html
   sw.js
   styles.css
```

And I'm trying to register it with the following code in my`index.html`:

```
<body>
  <app-root>Cargando...</app-root>
  <script>
      if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/sw.js',{scope: './'})
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Service Worker Registered. ");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("Service Worker failed to register: " + err);
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Service what?");
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

The problem is, when I run the dev server (I'm using Angular CLI, so webkit-dev-server I guess), it cannot find sw.js (is it not "included" on compilation?). But if I add it as a asset, I could register it sucessfully using `navigator.serviceWorker.register('assets/sw.js')`, but the SW scope now changes to`/assets/`, when I want to be just`/`.

How can I register the Service Worker in the root scope?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your serviceworker file `sw.js` to stay in the src directory and still be included as an asset, you have to add it to your `.angular-cli.json` under assets:

#### .angular-cli.json

```
  (...)
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "sw.js"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  (...)
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but this error appears:

`Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

It seems to me that somehow`sw.js`is not being included at all in the assets.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use the service worker provided by the angular mobile toolkit. https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/issues/138
They only work, when you do `ng serve --prod` resp. `ng build --prod`

Comment: I fixed the problem going to the last commit of my repo. I think something could have happened with some npm packages. I'll accept your answer because your indications are the intended way to doing it (assuming no other problems, of course, as in my case). Thank you for your help.